# JSF template not working

Tags: eclipse, jsf, jsf-2

please check these eclipse project hierarchy and tell me what is going wrong, why the template that i defined inside `/WEB-INF/template/` not appearing when i run the home page that's placed in `/Home.xhtml` ? when i run Home.xhtml the only thing that appears is the text "Main Content Area" without any template!

Thanks.

Template.xhtml

[image]

Home.xhtml

[image]

Comment: As first step, always check the JSF-generated HTML output by rightclick, *View Source* in browser. What do you see in there? Are all JSF tags parsed and rendered into HTML? If not (thus they appear plain/unparsed in the HTML output), then you simply didn't invoke the faces servlet at all. You'd need to post the faces servlet configuration detail in your question in order to get an proper answer to that.